# How do I use zfdatagrid library in my application

Tags: php, zend-framework, zfdatagrid

I am seeking to learn how to implement a grid in an application I am working on and I figured I will use zfdatagrid as it seems to take care of some of the features I need. However there is not much by way of tutorial on the net. Probably because its easy to figure out, but thing is I need help to understand how use it. I will appreaciate any link that can help or if one will be kind to give me some pointers here.

Thanks.

I now get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Bvb_Grid' not
>   found in
>   D:\www\lab\zfdatagrid\application\controllers\IndexController.php

and below is my indexAction

```
public function indexAction()
{
    //Zend_Config
    $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(getcwd().'\..\application\grids\grid.ini', 'production');
    var_dump($config);

//Grid Initialization
$grid = Bvb_Grid::factory('Bvb_Grid_Deploy_Table', $config, 'id');

//Setting grid source
$grid->setSource(new Bvb_Grid_Source_Zend_Table(new Bugs()));

//CRUD Configuration
$form = new Bvb_Grid_Form();
$form->setAdd(true)->setEdit(true)->setDelete(true);
$grid->setForm($form);

//Pass it to the view
$this->view->pages = $grid;
$this->render('index');

}
```

The Bvb library is located in the Library folder.

Well silly me I found the solution to the problem in another Stack Overflow thread [Zend Framework 1.10 custom Class inside library folder not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492365/zend-framework-1-10-custom-class-inside-library-folder-not-found)

I thought of deleting the question then I thought this may save someone following this thread a google.

Comment: demos: http://zfdatagrid.com/grid/ and example http://code.google.com/p/zfdatagrid/